# Show 3 figures with captions next to each other using css

Tags: html, css

I have 3 figures with captions. I want them horizontally aligned in the middle of the page, side by side, but all I can get is three vertical one. Using only HTML5 & CSS, how do I accomplish this?

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
        <figure>
            <img src="person-3593657_960_720.jpg" alt="Run">
            <figcaption>Running</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="people-2581913_1280.jpg" alt="Shopping">
            <figcaption>Shopping</figcaption>
        <figure>
            <img src="family-2609528_640.jpg" alt="people jumping in air">
            <figcaption>Spending time with friends & family</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    .row figure {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        padding: 5px;
    }

   .row figure img {
       margin:auto;
       padding:auto;
       width: 30%;
       box-shadow: rgb(101, 101, 101) 10px 10px 25px; 
   }

   .row figure figcaption {
       color: rgb(19, 7, 122);
       font: italic smaller sans-serif;
       padding: 3px;
       text-align: center;
   }
```

Comment: please check my post.

Comment: Here is the solution I came up with:
https://codepen.io/webdevgirl/pen/RmVWwy

Answer (score 0):

Change `flex-flow: column;` to `flex-flow: row;` or `flex-flow: row-reverse;`

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing closing figure tag that is one of the reasons why you could not achieve what you wanted.

I use `display: flex` and implicitly mention `flex-direction: row`(optional) to lay the figures out horizontally and by specifying `width: 100%;` it will take full width (100%) of the container; in this case, the body element.

`justify-content: center` will center the content of the div.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /*
  The below properties are demo purpose. Feel free to change it to fit your needs. 
  */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <figure>
    <img src="person-3593657_960_720.jpg" alt="Run">
    <figcaption>Running</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="people-2581913_1280.jpg" alt="Shopping">
    <figcaption>Shopping</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="family-2609528_640.jpg" alt="people jumping in air">
    <figcaption>Spending time with friends & family</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```